# How to run systemd services in Arch Linux Docker container?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, docker

There seems to be tons of different ways people have been able to run systemd services within Docker containers. The latest example of [direct advice](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20082#issuecomment-183817257) I've found is to run Docker with `--volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined`. However, it still just [fails](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/root/builds/154572430#L2365):

> Error: Could not start Service[ntpd]: Execution of '/usr/sbin/systemctl start ntpd' returned 1: Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

What is the absolute minimum I need to do to get simple services running under systemd 231 on a docker 1.12.1 container with an up-to-date Arch Linux distribution?

Comment: Docker is more about running the daemon directly once you give it a predefined `ENTRYPOINT` systemd doesn't factor into it. If you're looking for some sort of container integration with systemd you can [look into creating an nspawn service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn)

Comment: I'm not using Docker to run a single service. I'm using it to test a Puppet run which (among other things) starts multiple services. If I special case the test environment (use nspawn instead of systemd) the test is kind of useless.

Comment: "I'm not using Docker to run a single service" Then you can't use Docker at all. It's intended to run a single executable and everything is built around that fact. That's probably why this problem is so hard for you to solve. If you're testing a puppet run, what I usually do in that case is have a VM that I snapshot prior to doing the run. If you have something like Vagrant setup already it's pretty easy to just build new VM's and blow them away (as opposed to doing a snapshot).

Comment: The immediate problem you appear to be having though is that dbus isn't running inside your container.

Comment: I'm using Docker for this work for two reasons: Layers are easier to work with than snapshots to avoid large amounts of unnecessary work when re-running tests, and the current Docker setup is *much* simpler than the corresponding Vagrant one. I don't see why Docker should preclude running multiple services - they are just processes, after all. There's nothing stopping anyone from running multiple processes in Docker. I don't want any of them to be the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: "I don't see why Docker should preclude running multiple services" It's not really a question of if it's possible, it's just not how docker containers are designed to be used. They're supposed to encapsulate a single daemon that you're trying to serve out. I really think you're over-engineering this. I've developed puppet code for a while and generally speaking you don't really need to go back to a snapshot at all unless there's some dependency problem in your code. Obviously you should still test for dependency issues but they're probably going to be an outlier in terms of problems you find.

Comment: Basically puppet code describes the end-state a machine should be in so just doing iterative runs is usually enough to get to know your code does what you're expecting it will do. Your testing should just involve reverting to snapshot once or twice to make sure you're not missing something like a `before =>` or a `notify =>` somewhere.

Comment: if you need to use systemd in docker , then conclude that you are doing something wrong , reconsider your design and implementation

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem testing my Ansible playbooks which require systemd. And as you said, docker seems like the best approach here as it is much easier to bring up and down a container rather than a virtual machine.
First of all **base/archlinux** image is deprecated - you should use **archlinux/base** instead.
Then, to run systemd totally unprivileged, number of things should be done:

- provide a `container=` variable, so systemd won't try to do number of things it usually does booting a hardware machine
- systemd actively uses cgroups, so bind mount `/sys/fs/cgroup` file system from a host
- bind mounting `/sys/fs/fuse` is not required but helps to avoid issues with fuse-dependent software
- systemd thinks that using `tmpfs` everywhere is a good approach, but running unprivileged makes it impossible for it to mount `tmpfs` where ever it wants, so pre-mount `tmpfs` to `/tmp`, `/run` and `/run/lock`
- as the last bit you need to specify `sysinit.target` as default unit to boot instead of `multi-user.target` or whatever, as you really do not want to start graphical things inside a container

The resulting command line is

```
docker run \
  --entrypoint=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd \
  --env container=docker \
  --mount type=bind,source=/sys/fs/cgroup,target=/sys/fs/cgroup \
  --mount type=bind,source=/sys/fs/fuse,target=/sys/fs/fuse \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run/lock \
    archlinux/base --log-level=info --unit=sysinit.target
```

If we are talking about running particular service there like ntpd from your example you will need to add

```
--cap-add=SYS_TIME
```

otherwise `ntpd` will fail with permission deny as nobody wants a container to set system time by default.
P.s I spent quite a while learning how systemd behaves and managed to get it working on number of operating system images. I described my experience in an article [Running systemd in docker container](https://www.hippolab.ru/zapuskaem-systemd-v-docker-konteynere). It is in Russian but I believe google translate should work in your browser. Thanks

Comment: I just experimented a problem related to cgroups : your container cgroup version must match the one of the host, or you will get an error like "Failed to create /init.scope control group: Read-only file system".
This is manageable through the boot flag systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=[0|1], 0 for v1, 1 for v2.

Comment: @Hexdump You spared me a headache! Looks like cgroups v2 is default as of systemd v248: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/993eb00016a75cf085eed85cf626a6995e96ab3d/NEWS#L2381 and https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/993eb00016a75cf085eed85cf626a6995e96ab3d/NEWS#L379. Also, `archlinux/base` has since been deprecated https://hub.docker.com/r/archlinux/base. https://hub.docker.com/r/archlinux/archlinux is the successor as of now.